# Почему [0] != "" и [] != "0" и [[]] != "0"?

Tags: javascript

Просто было бы логично если бы `[0] == ""` т.к. обе части приводятся к нулю.

Или ещё вопрос, почему `[] != "0"` и `[[]] != "0"` ведь тут так же обе части приводятся к нулю.

http://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/

```js
console.log(Number([0]));
console.log(Number(""));
console.log(Number([]));
console.log(Number([[]]));
console.log(Number("0"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> обе части приводятся к нулю

Не приводятся. Массив приводится к строке, получаем две строки и сравниваются строки. А они, очевидно, разные. А вот если бы в правой части было число, то в сравнении строки и числа строка бы привелась к числу, из-за чего равенство бы выполнилось:

```js
console.log([] == "")
console.log([] == 0)
console.log([] == "0")
console.log([0] == "")
console.log([0] == 0)
console.log([0] == "0")
```

Comment: о как оказывается!

Comment: А такое строковое преобразование при сравнении разных типов только с массивом происходит?

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/object-conversion